# How to use SOAP with Qlik

Tags: web-services, soap, birt, qlikview

So I'm evaluating this tool called QLIK over BIRT which should be used to pull and represent data from a SOAP service.

In BIRT I basically just supply the WSDL and I'm done. If I want to do the same with QLIK they tell us in the tutorial to use an external tool to create the SOAP Request and then use it as POST in something they call "Web Connector", which I can't find anywhere in the UI.

Am I missing something here or is it basically not possible to use SOAP services with QLIK inside the tool?
Bonus points if you can tell me where this "Web Connector" is.

Also I find it pretty confusing that they offer a REST connection but no SOAP connection on the datasource selection page?

I did find a place to configure a SOAP service in a menu called "SalesForce" shich is as far as I understand some 3th party service. This all makes totally no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options to do this as I understand it, however I've not worked with SOAP/WDSL myself.

1. Use the [REST Connector](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/REST_connector_help/Content/1.1/ReleaseInfo/Release-info-11.htm) which is included with Qlik Sense v2 but is also free for earlier versions of Qlik Sense and QlikView. This allows you to issue a POST command rather than a GET command. The request body would presumably be the XML.
2. Use the "[General Web Connector](http://wiki.qvsource.com/General-Web-Connector-For-QlikView.ashx)" from "Qlik Web Connectors". This is an add-on that you have to subscribe to, so if the REST one works for you, there's probably not much reason to go for it. That said, the documentation for it is more useful with some [worked](http://wiki.qvsource.com/How-To-Call-A-SOAP-Web-Service-From-QlikView-With-Help-From-SoapUI-And-QVSource.ashx) [examples](http://wiki.qvsource.com/How-To-Call-A-SOAP-Web-Service-From-QlikView-Manual-Example.ashx). (The background here is that Qlik bought a company that made a tool called QVSource earlier this year - hence the overlap between these two approaches and why the documentation is still branded as QVSource)

Hope that helps, sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I will give it a try !